# How do I convert a string into safe SQL String?

Tags: .net, sql, sanitization

I'm generating some sql insert statements from a bunch of text files.

These text files are generally user input data. I would like to sanitize this data so that it's not going to break the insert statement.

For example, some of the input data, people have used the word Don't. The "'" in don't will lead the sql statement to think the string has ended and therefore cause an error.

Is there any .NET method I can call to kind of convert all of these characters to either escape codes or safe characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating safe SQL statements as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293254/creating-safe-sql-statements-as-strings)

Comment: Use parameterized queries (see linked question).

Comment: The answer there says to input the data into parameters. I'm simply trying to generate the script via looking at the text files. My program isn't actually going to call the database, just spit out the scripts.

Comment: Not sure how your reply addresses the recommendation that you use parameterized queries.  The scripts you are generating would simply be scripts that use parameterized queries--you don't actually have to call the database.

Comment: @Tim: "simply be scripts that use parameterized queries" - how? What does an `.sql` script file look like with parametrized queries? Wouldn't the parameter values have to be escaped again when they are written into that file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't sanitize your strings. Use parameterized queries instead, as they handle all sanitization.

You don't specify which database you are using, so I assume it is MS SQL Server. Microsoft has [an article](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs) on the official ASP.net website about this. Also see MSDN for [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) and the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method.

Comment: +1 there is no "safe" way to concatenate together SQL statements - using **parametrized queries** (**ALWAYS!**) is the only viable way to go

Comment: @marc_s: Parameterized queries are only a partial solution. They don't protect against SQL injection into a dynamic SQL query, javascript injection into a varchar field, parameter injection into an html label, etc.  There is no "silver bullet" solution to injection.

Comment: @Andomar That's a different problem though: Parameterized Queries offer 100% protection against SQL Injection, that is "Injection of unwanted SQL into another SQL Statement". The other side is Output Encoding, aka. HTML Encoding all user data that is output into a website to prevent stuff like XSS. That is an entirely different problem, one that is much harder. I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic SQL query" - even when building a query with StringBuilders you can easily add parameters? (Parameterized Queries are NOT stored procedures after all, they can be dynamically generated)

Comment: See [this example](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection) for how dynamic SQL enables SQL Injection, even though you use a .NET parameterized query

Comment: @Andomar I see. That seems to be a rather unusual way of doing it though: Why would anyone use T-SQL and EXEC if they are already coding in .net? In .net I would just do `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(custName)){ sb.Append(" AND customerName = @custName"); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName",custName); } cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();` and be done with it.

Comment: @Andomar I think I understand it now. Indeed, you are right. If your Stored Procedure is dynamically concatenating strings, then parameterized queries won't do much.

Comment: DO sanitise untrusted input because of persistent XSS for one.

Comment: @jhsowter Not on the database side. XSS is a much bigger problem and should be handled in an appropriate layer - don't ever put it in the database to begin with, and never render out anything from the database without encoding it.

Comment: @MichaelStum I have thought a bit more and I agree you should validate the string for XSS and then store it if it's safe. That is, validate, but do not sanitise. Let a framework sanitise the string for you.

Comment: @MichaelStum Unfortunately, you can't use a parameterized query with the "ORDER BY" clause. (At least in Sql Server)

Comment: @marc_s (& Mr. Stum) I understand that parameterized queries are always preferred, but that's also just offloading the problem -- *somebody's* writing the code that does that cleanup within the parameterization ;). If for no other reason than for a thought experiment, can you explain why [Andormar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529426/1028230) *wouldn't* work for string params in, eg, the `{0}` in `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name='{0}'`? Or TryParse for an int? Etc. What makes conventional use cases too complicated for the general dev public?

Comment: The OP says they want to write the `INSERT` statements into SQL script files. It's not clear from this answer how parametrized queries would work in those. Once the parameter values are written into the script files, they still have to be escaped in some way.

Comment: How do you use parametrerized queries when you want to use `thecol like '%foobar%'`?

Comment: @marc_s, There is always (almost always) an exception to every rule. When you use SQL Server and you have more than 2100 elements in an `IN` or `NOT IN` predicate, you cannot use parameters, you need to resort to literals.

Comment: @JesúsLópez: if you have more than 2100 elements for an `IN` clause - you have quite a few other problems to deal with first......

Comment: @marc_s. Most of the time we can use a subquery. But in some extreme cases we have no better alternative.

Comment: @JesúsLópez: if you really need 2100+ elements - why aren't those stored in a separate table (possibly a temp table) so you can just easily **join** - instead of having such a monster of an `IN` clause?? There's always a better alternative than 2100+ elements in an `IN`!

Comment: @marc_s. Yes, I see this sound weird.But trust me, I saw rare scenarios where It make sense.

Comment: @marc_s. The large `IN` scenario is not the only one you need literals. Think about a bunch of insert, update and delete statements in a single batch. It's very easy to have more than 2100 values is this scenario, in this case you need literals.

Answer (score 39):

There is only a single character you have to escape: ansi 0x27, aka the single quote:

```
safeString = unsafeString.Replace("'","''");
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP is quoting all values in their `insert` statement though. If they are generating a string like this `INSERT INTO T1(numeric,string) values (1,'some string')` then it won't help if they have some unexpected bad data in the first column. (e.g. `'1,2); DROP TABLE ...'`

Comment: @MartinSmith Then use int.TryParse for the first parameter to ensure its a clean integer.

Comment: What about commas in an insert statement?

Comment: This is enough for me. I included it in my micro ORM (EntityLite) for very large `IN` predicates, to workaround the 2100 SQL Server max number of parameters. I hope there is no more characters to take care of. I think I was too much paranoid with SQL injection.

Comment: @JohanAspeling a comma within single quotations should not cause a problem. But if it occurred where you did not expect a string then the other comment about TryParse for a numeric value would take care of it

Comment: Lol is this really the only think to take care of ? In this case people really are too paranoid x) Parametrized queries are painful to maintain and don't look nice

Comment: This doesn't sanitize the data as per the OP if the sproc is using dynamic SQL. Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102387/how-to-cleanse-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Anyone found any case where this isn't enough? What better way to sanitize the data? (except from Parameterized Queries)

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of both would be a good practice generally.
On the code behind (assumes that the textbox only accepts numbers:

```
    strSQL="exec GetMember" & SanitizeInput(ID)
    *do your db call*

    Public Function SanitizeInput(byval InputString as String)
      Dim OutputString=replace(InputString,"'","''")
      OutputString=replace(OutputString,"<script>","")
      OutputString=replace(OutputString,"DROP","")
      *... and more rules...*
      Return OutputString
    End Function
```

On your SQl Sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMember
@ID int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select {whatevercolumns} from Members where ID=@ID
END
GO
```