# Database injection prevention c#

Tags: c#, sql-injection

```
public ActionResult PostMessage(string message)
{
    MessageController mc = new MessageController();
    mc.postMessage(message);
}
```

What can I do here to prevent SQL injection in this string? This is the only input the user is given on the entire page. I am familiar with the some PHP techniques, but how would I protect myself in c#?

Thanks!

edit:

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[tblMessages_Insert]", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// params
SqlParameter messageText = new SqlParameter("@messageText", SqlDbType.VarChar);
messageText.Value = message;

// add params
command.Parameters.Add(messageText);

rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I would imagine it depends on what database API you're using!

Comment: in .net - system.data.sqlclient

Comment: What are you using to store data in your database?  If you are using DbCommands and parameters correctly or an ORM, you should be protected automatically.  I would be more concerned about CSS issues if you are taking that user message and writing it back out to HTML at some point later in your app.

Comment: @Scott - let's see that database access code.  Without seeing that I couldn't really say for certain..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string into safe SQL String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528972/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-safe-sql-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're already protecting against injection; you're using parameters.

Comment: Parameterized stored procedures provide some inherent protection against injection.  However if you're building and executing dynamic sql inside the procedure, look out :)

Comment: yes I know... but based on the name of his stored proc it seemed unlikely that anything dynamic was going on :)