# OperationalError: near ")": syntax error in sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Below is my code:

```
# export data to sqlite
    with sqlite3.connect('realtime_crypto.sqlite') as conn:
        df.to_sql('data', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Below is the error showing

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 218>()
    232 # export data to sqlite
    233 with sqlite3.connect('realtime_crypto.sqlite') as conn:
--> 234     df.to_sql('data', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

```
OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

I tried changing the format still not working.

Comment: What are the columns?  Are they all strings?

Comment: Why are you using sqlite3 connection context manager with pandas? Do you understand what it does and when it should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have single quotes in your dataframe.

I would recommend to use `pyathena.pandas.util.to_sql` function so if the value contains single quotes, it will be automatically escaped:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyathena.pandas.util import to_sql

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar", "jim o'rourke"]})
to_sql(df, "test", conn)
```

[How do I convert a string into safe SQL String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528972/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-safe-sql-string)

https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/issues/238