# Escaping user input in SQL parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-3.5

I have the following `WHERE` condition in a `SELECT` statement:

```
WHERE ('.' + column_name LIKE @prefix))
```

And the `@prefix` parameter is set as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefix", "%[^a-z]" & prefix & "%")
```

The `prefix` variable is taken from form input.

The problem I'm having is when the user enters a '%' or '[' or other special character. How can I make sure these are escaped rather than being treated as special characters?

Related: Generally, how do you stop people entering '%' in their input and having this treated as a wildcard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cleanse dynamic SQL in SQL Server -- prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102387/how-to-cleanse-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @PreetSangha I think this question is narrower in scope, because it asks for escaping metacharacters in `LIKE` expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL's `LIKE` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) provides an optional `ESCAPE` clause:

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

You can set the escape character to a single character of your liking, and escape metacharacters with it.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this for my query?

Comment: @Andrew You can use `Regex.Replace(prefix, "[~%_[\\]]", "!$0")` to escape your prefix with the exclamation point `!`, and then use exclamation point in your escape clause: `column_name LIKE @prefix ESCAPE '!'`.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed to `prefix = Regex.Replace(prefix, "[!~%_[\]]", "!$0")`. I gather the `!` needs to be escaped since it is the escape character. Also, why did you include `~`?

Comment: @Andrew "why did you include ~?" Because it is next to the `!` on the keyboard, so I pressed the wrong key :) It was supposed to be `[!%_[\\]]`.