# Execute sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table called Emp contain `id,name,lname,birthdate,address and salery` .I want to select from emp.
Basic query : `select * from emp`
If pass the value for lname ,query : `select * from emp where lname = 'fgfg'` like this.
So I created following sp.

```
create Procedure Proc_selectEmp
(
@name varchar(10) = null,
@lname varchar(10) = null,
@id varchar(10) = null

)
as
begin

select * from Emp
where 
(@name is null or name = @name) 
and (@lname is null or lname = @lname) 
and (@id is null or id = @id)
end
```

Like emp,there are 13 table having same column name.
So my tablenmae is also dynamic.That's why, I choose execute sp_executesql.Can I create like this

```
create Procedure Proc_selectEmp
(
@name varchar(10) = null,
@lname varchar(10) = null,
@id varchar(10) = null
@tableName varchar(30)
)
as
begin
declare @query nvarchar(1000) 
set @query = @query +'select * from '+@tableName+'
where ('+@name+' is null or name = '+@name+') 
and ('+@lname+' is null or lname = '+@lname+') 
and ('+@id+' is null or id = '+@id+')
end'

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: I can't find the question. Do you have a question?

Comment: If the question was: "Can I build SQL dynamically?" then the answer is "Yes".

Comment: But read up on SQL injection. And use `QUOTENAME`. See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL - Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames)

Answer (score 1):

It will work, although is pretty smelly, given that it requires that it requires that table name is a variable and thus tables must have the same column definitions.

Also, rather than including the `@param is null or column = @param`, rather, leave out unnecessary filters entirely, which is easy to do since you are using dynamic sql. This will avoid the [parameter sniffing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server).

Lastly, instead of appending the column filters into the string, rather use the parameterized overload of `sp_executesql`, which will protect your from SQL injection attacks, and handle the escaping of quotes etc for you. Unfortunately, @tablename can't be parameterized, but hopefully? this isn't a user or foreign-supplied variable (in which case you will need to do some more thinking about design and or validation techniques).

i.e.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) 
set @query = N'select * from ' + @tableName + N` where (1=1)`

if (@name is not null)
  set @query = @query + N'and name = @name'

-- ... same for @id and @lname

exec sp_executesql @SQL, 
     N'@name varchar(10),
       @lname varchar(10),
       @id varchar(10)',
       @name = @name,
       @lname = @lname,
       @id = @id
```

**Edit**
Re : securing `un-parameterizable` inputs like table or column names in dynamic sql - [see this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102387/how-to-cleanse-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-prevent-sql-injection) for ideas - use of  `QUOTENAME` and white-listing column / table names are prominent.

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can but you have to write

```
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Instead of

```
execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: No you don't. `sp_executesql` is generally preferred as you can parameterise at least some parts.

Comment: I am sorry but in his case he dont need it. Execute is perfect for his case.

Comment: Your wording "*you have to write*" ... "*instead of*"... makes it seem like you are saying `sp_executesql` specifically *won't work*, which is patently false.

Comment: Sorry for the terms, but I am not English native :)