# Must Declare Scalar variable - Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I keep getting an error that says:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@DeviceSearch".]
```

Even though the value is being passed into the Stored Procedure. Here is the SQL Trace:

```
exec InventorySearch @FieldName=N'Value',@TableName=N'AssetTag',@SearchTerm=N'00002730',@DeviceSearch=1
```

Here is the variable declaration in the Stored Procedure and also the line that is using it:

```
@DeviceSearch nvarchar(50),
@FieldName AS nvarchar(50),
@TableName AS nvarchar(50),
@SearchTerm nvarchar(50)

WHERE (@DeviceSearch = 1 and LogicallyDeleted = 0 and '+ @TableName+ '.'+ @FieldName+ 
                                                            ' like ''%@SearchTerm%'')
```

Can anyone see what I need to do to correct this?

Comment: Well, by only seeing a limited part of what seems to be some dynamic SQL, it will be hard to help you

Comment: You are passing integer data whereas datatype for `@DeviceSearch` is defined as nvarchar. Try to change Data Type on one end and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Debug Your Query using output from *print statements* while executing query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InventorySearch] 
    @FieldName AS nvarchar(50),
    @TableName AS nvarchar(50), 
    @SearchTerm nvarchar(50),
    @DeviceSearch bit
AS 
BEGIN
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=

'SELECT AssetTag.Value, Device.LK_User, Device.LK_Location,
        AssetTag.CreatedOn, Device.AssetTypeId, AssetTag.StatusTypeId, 
        Device.DeviceID, Device.SerialNumber, Device.LogicallyDeleted
 FROM Device INNER JOIN AssetTag ON Device.DeviceID = AssetTag.DeviceID  
 WHERE '+CAST(@DeviceSearch as nvarchar(5))+'=1 and LogicallyDeleted = 0 and '+ (@TableName)+ '.'+ 
          (@FieldName) 
        +' like ''%' + (@SearchTerm ) +'%'''

print (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Comment: CAST(@DeviceSearch as nvarchar(5)) on device search took care of it. Thank You for the suggestion of using the print(@SQL). I am new to writing Stored procedures and had never seen that before.

One other question ... I have seen where people bring up SQL Injection concerns when using Dynamic SQL and rightly so. 

Is there anything I should consider with this answer or do you know of some good references I can look at?

Comment: @michaelk46 you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102387/how-to-cleanse-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-prevent-sql-injection and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx

Comment: @michaelk46 its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

try this i believe it will help

```
   exec
InventorySearch 
@FieldName=N'Value',
@TableName=N'AssetTag',
@SearchTerm=N'00002730',
@DeviceSearch='1'
```

and also

```
WHERE (@DeviceSearch = '1' and LogicallyDeleted = 0
       and '+ @TableName+ '.'+ @FieldName+ 
      ' like ''%@SearchTerm%'')
```